# How to set the regex to "w", "e" and "b" keys in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to define what vim should recognize as a word? I want to assign \w+ regex to all word key motions such as "w", "e", "b"... I can do it for normal mode like this:

```
nnoremap <silent> w :call search('\w\+')<CR>
```

but it doesn't work for visual mode and operator-pending modes. It would be great if there is a setting to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, and the discussion on Kaz' answer, I think what you're looking for is Kana's smartword plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2470.

You're going to have to check the documentation with [`:help smartword`](https://github.com/kana/vim-smartword/blob/master/doc/smartword.txt), but the short version is, if you install the plugin and map the built-in word mappings to the plugin ones...

```
map w  <Plug>(smartword-w)
map b  <Plug>(smartword-b)
map e  <Plug>(smartword-e)
map ge  <Plug>(smartword-ge)
```

... then the built-ins will skip any non-word characters along the way. I've been using this for many, many years, and I'm quite happy with the way it behaves.

Comment: This is exactly what I looked for. Normal, visual and operator-pending modes work fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the lower-case motions like <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>e</kbd>, the definition of a "word" is controlled by the `:iskeyword` option; see the `:help iskeyword` on that. Basically it consists of a list of characters given as individual characters or ranges, separated by commas. I think that various syntax files tweak this for different languages, so that these commands move by identifiers. It doesn't look like you can specify a regular expression for this.

The upper-case motions like <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> don't look like they can be reprogrammed. Their definition of a "WORD" is nonblank characters separated by whitespace, plus that each empty line counts as a "WORD".

However, unfortunately, it looks like there is a behavior in effect whereby the `iskeyword` characters simply separate the input into sequences of `iskeyword` characters, non-`iskeyword` characters and whitespace. When the <kbd>w</kbd> and related commands are used, they skip whitespace, but visit both the `iskeyword` tokens and the non-`iskeyword` tokens.

Remapping using `:map` to just a `/` or `?` keystroke sequence works in both visual and command mode:

```
:map w /\<\w/^M
:map b ?\</\w^M
:map e /\w\>^M
```

It works in both because the `/` and `?` searches work in both modes. Of course, it's an ugly solution because it clobbers the current search pattern and if you have `:set hls` (`highlightsearch`) on, the tips/tails of the words highlight.

The above searches are not very satisfactory because of the way the anchoring operators are behaving. For instance, I can't get them to "land" on the `a` in something like `{abc` or `(abc`.

The following mappings work a better. Each triggers several searches. The `/.` and `?.` searches are used as a trick to go to the
next or previous character, such that if we are on the last character of a line, we go to the first one on the next line and vice versa.

```
:map b ?\w^M?\W^M/.^M
:map w /\W^M/\w^M
:map e /\w^M/\W^M?.^M
```

There are still some quirks. For instance, a list of words like:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

contains no match for the non-word class `\W`. The matching has to include line endings. Moving forward, an improvement to the <kbd>w</kbd> one in this regard is to add a match for the line ending like this:

```
:map w /\(\W\\|$\)^M/\w^M
```

Note the double backslash before the pipe! The rightmost backslash escapes the pipe so the processing of the `:map` command doesn't treat it as a command delimiter. Then we are left with `\|` which is the regex operator for branching.  In a similar vein, the other two mappings can be improved; I'm leaving that as an exercise.

Comment: Well, I've changed this option to "48-57,65-90,97-122,_", and nothing is happened. Maybe I was inaccurate in my question. I want to skip all symbols like $, = or -> and anything like that when I move via "w" key.


`au BufEnter * setlocal iskeyword=48-57,65-90,97-122,_`

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like Vim treats the characters *outside* of the set as words also, other than whitespace. So if we define `iskeyword` as, say, just the lower-case a-z, and we have the cursor on the `a` in `abc$def`, then `w` will visit the `$` and then the `def`.  Basically the text is tokenized into words separated by non-words, but then `w` visits both of them!

Comment: Looks like rebinding the keys to do a custom search is probably the only way to go. For instance `:map w /\<\w^M`  (`^M` entered as Ctrl-V Enter). Unfortunately this clobbers the current search pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your attention but as you said it will clobber current search (not critical) and highlight all occurrences (it's critical). I knew that I can call function in visual mode but it's too much configuration. I thought there is a better way, for instance, setting an option. If there will be no other messages I'll mark your one as an answer.

Comment: I usually have a key mapped to toggle `hls` because `hls` can be  annoying in various circumstances even when search isn't clobbered.

Comment: You may use `:noh` command or `:let @/ = ""` - which is faster.